# Return an array created from custom objects in Swift where they aren't known until runtime?

Tags: swift

This function works fine except for the return

```
func fillAnObjectClassArrayGivenURL(URL: String, className: NSObject) -> [NSObject] {
var returnList = [className]
var objectToAddToList = className
...
//some code that appends objectToAddToList to returnList
return returnList
}
```

But this `[NSObject]` isn't the right thing to return and I don't know what class it will be making the array from until runtime. Not that swift with Swift yet. Is there a way to return essentially `[className]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics.

```
func fillAnObjectClassArrayGivenURL<T: AnyObject>(urlString: String, className: T.Type) -> [T]
```

Comment: I'll need to study up on this. I did make a change to `func fillAnObjectClassArrayGivenURL<T: NSObject>(urlString: String, className: T) -> [T]{` and it worked for my code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, I thought I had it. But then noticed the objects in the array all share the same value. How do you reinitialize and object in a generic?